# Excel Protecting Rows and Columns but Allowing Cell Editing

Tags: excel, protected

I need to make a template where the rows and columns cannot be deleted but the cells can still be edited

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to get this to work please

Answer (score 0):

Select all the cells in the sheet and unlock them

Take a cell that doesn't need to be edited (there must be at least *one* somewhere on the sheet) and lock it.

[image]

Activate sheet protection

You're done

Comment: Every time I try to protect the worksheet (I've tried a few different tactics with the protection) it wont let me edit the other cells. We have cells that can be protected but ultimately its the rows and columns that can't be deleted that we need

Comment: Did you make sure that `Locked` is **unchecked** for those cells you want to edit?

Comment: Got it! Thank you!! I knew I was missing something obvious! I just did it backwards  the first time I tried.